# Is there a way to "npm install" from AWS S3?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, microservices

Is there a way to store projects/modules on AWS S3 and do an `npm install` from a client project?

I've found a way to do an `npm install` from BitBucket in the npm docs [[Go]](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install)

I'm trying to find different ways to store common project items (i.e. methods or other resources) to use across microservices.

Comment: I used a private subscription to http://npmjs.org and used a private repository. You only need one user and then can create private read-only keys for your users (including CI) that need access

Comment: You can now just use AWS CodeArtifact https://aws.amazon.com/codeartifact/ instead if you want to have package repository in AWS.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the documentation, you should be able to install a package from any url resolving to a gzipped tarball.

So if you expose your bucket content with cloudfront, it should work.

> A package is:
>
> - a) a folder containing a program described by a package.json file
> - b) a gzipped tarball containing (a)
> - c) a url that resolves to (b)
> - d) a @ that is published on the registry with (c)
> - e) a @ that points to (d)
> - f) a  that has a "latest" tag satisfying (e)
> - g) a git url that, when cloned, results in (a).

doc : https://docs.npmjs.com/about-packages-and-modules#about-packages

Comment: That is not entirely true, as https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install also states that to use URI "the argument must start with "http://" or "https://". Which means no `s3://` URIs are acceptable. https:// for S3 can cause problems with authorization.

Comment: @RafałWrzeszcz see [How do I use CloudFront to serve HTTPS requests for my Amazon S3 bucket?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudfront-https-requests-s3/)

Comment: I'm not saying it's a problem with service HTTPS content from S3 - I'm saying it's a problem with authrorization. The point is to make this a private repository, not to make all packages available publicly.

Comment: You can probably use a signed URL to protect the access to the module over HTTPS

Comment: Thanks, it does work. I have created a my-package@1.0.0.tar.gz  and uploaded it to S3. Then I provided the S3's HTTPS URL in  package.json